# Date format issue in android

Tags: java, simpledateformat

In android
am getting date in
**(date = "04-01-2013")** this format

but i want to show same date in
en.US format like **`(date="Friday,January 04,2013")`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

set input pattern matching input date string: `"04-01-2013" -> "dd-MM-yyyy"`.

And output pattern like output: `"Friday, January 04, 2013" -> "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"`

```
public String formatDate(String input){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date d = sdf.parse(input);
    sdf.applyPattern("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
    return sdf.format(d,new StringBuffer(),0).toString();
}
```

Comment: thnk u boss u saved my lots of time n it works for me so rely thnk from my bottom of heart

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
      DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
      DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
      return df2.format(df1.parse(input));
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy", new java.util.Date());
```

Take a look at [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html).

Comment: thnk all of you love u alllllll buddy

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in java

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM dd,yyyy");
java.util.Date date=df.parse("04-01-2013");
```

refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: how shold i store result of 
df.parse("04-01-2013")

String res=df.parse("04-01-2013");