# Convert String value to Date format

Tags: android, string, date-format

I want to convert string value to date format i have the string like

```
String date = 1360004238;
```

I am able to get like this `Fri Jan 16 23:43:30 GMT+05:30 1970`

How could i convert it to date format like (for example "23 February 2013")

Could anybody help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14157339/1531054

Comment: What is that? Epoch time?

Comment: You assign a number to a String variable? Thats a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some thing like this..

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E,MMM dd,yyyy h:mmaa");   

                        String today = formatter.format(newdate);
```

For more info you can check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Date d = new Date(date);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
format.format(d);
```

where `date` is a `long`, not a `String`.

Comment: Here in this case is it applicable or not

Comment: That's compile error. You either have String date = "23142" or long date = 31242353;

Comment: First parse it to a long. Long.parseLong(date);

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String date = 1360004238;
System.out.println(new Date(date).toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is holding an epoch timestamp, you can do:

```
String epoch = "number";
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(epoch));
```

Comment: Which order are you referring to?